# Orbbec Astra Mini S - Depth calibration

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can calibrate the rgb image, but i don't get how it is possible to calibrate the depth image / depth cloud. Some help would be very nice :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296282/orbbec-astra-mini-s---depth-calibration/) by [Sokrates](https://answers.ros.org/users/30113/sokrates/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-07-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mikhail K.](https://answers.ros.org/users/35987/mikhail-k./) on 2018-07-05**:
Well, for Kinects subscription to ir is used. The following is for old camera_calibration module and a chess board

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py image:=/camera/ir/image_raw camera:=/camera/ir --size 8x6 --square 0.1
```

**Comment by [Sokrates](https://answers.ros.org/users/30113/sokrates/) on 2018-07-05**:
This calibration method is working for me for:
`image:=/camera/rgb/image_raw camera:=/camera/rgb`

However if i use the `ir/image_raw` the windows that opens freezes, and is unresponsive.
I tried `image:=/camera/depth/image_raw camera:=/camera/depth` but with this i only get a b&w depth image.

**Comment by [Mikhail K.](https://answers.ros.org/users/35987/mikhail-k./) on 2018-07-05**:
Well, I just followed the same procedure as with rgb and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved it!
Looks like my camera doesn't publish in the topic `/camera/ir/image_raw`, it publishes it in `/camera/ir/image`.

Now i can calibrate the camera.

---

Originally posted by [Sokrates](https://answers.ros.org/users/30113/sokrates/) with karma: 16 on 2018-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0